# How do I handle user leaving/closing the page effectively?

Tags: javascript

Okay, I have a live application, it runs a messenger and I am trying to find the most reliable way to determine if a user has navigated away from the page or closed the window, *et cetera*. I have already implemented this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event){ /* my code */ };
```

But that isn't always very reliable, sometimes it will fire and sometimes not. Is there a more reliable way of determining user presence or lack thereof?

Comment: Sometimes document.onblur will work, but it's also intermittent and depends on the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Have the browser *ping* the server every X minutes. If you're making a chat client you'll likely have all the infrastructure you need already.